# printing results in a formated form

Tags: c

I want to format the result so it would be adjusted

[image: output]

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
void affichage(int note[][50],char nom[][50],float moy[], float moy_e[], char module[][50],int nb_etudiant, int nb_module){
    int i,j;
    printf("\n\t\taffichage\n\n");
    printf("\t");
    strcpy(module[nb_module],"Moy G");
    strcpy(nom[nb_etudiant],"Moy C");
    for (i=0;i<nb_module;i++){
        printf("%5s ",module[i]);
    }
    printf("    %5s",module[nb_module]);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<nb_etudiant;i++){
        printf("%-5s ",nom[i]);
        for (j=0;j<nb_module;j++){
            printf("%-7d ", note[i][j]);
        }
        printf(" %-7.1f\n",moy_e[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("%5s    ",nom[nb_etudiant]);

    for (i=0;i<nb_module;i++){
        printf("%-7.1f ",moy[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As a suggestion, printf returns the length of the string formatted. 
 Since you want to display the student's data, if we suppose you have a table 
 with 2 columns:

```
     X chars       Y chars
-------|------ -------|---------
|             |                 |
----------------------------------------
nom           | prénom          |  note
----------------------------------------
 Jane         | Mari            |    15   
----------------------------------------
 Robert       | Daniel          |    16    
-----------------------------------------

X : number of white spaces - 2
Y : number of white space - 2
it can be any value, but make sure it will be greater than most of  
the lengths of the property displayed in that column
```

For Each student, for the first cell (nom) you should first print his name, then you get the length of the printed name PN (printf's returned value), and print ( X - PN) whitespace, then you add the pipe character |.
You do the same for the next property which is prenom, and at last you print \n for a new line.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char firstName[25];
    char lastName[25];
    float grade1;
    float grade2;
}Student;

Student createStudent(char* firstName, char* lastName, float grade1, float grade2) {
    Student student;

    strcpy(student.firstName, firstName);
    strcpy(student.lastName, lastName);
    student.grade1 = grade1;
    student.grade2 = grade2;

    return student;
}

/* each column has a width equal to 20 characters 2 for borders and 18 of whitespaces or characters */
void printBorder() {
    int i = 0;
    int len = 0;

    for(i =0 ; i<80; ++i) printf("-"); // top border
    printf("\n"); // breakline

    printf("|"); // left border of the left cell
    len = printf("First Name"); // len is equal to 10

    for(i=0; i<18 - len; ++i) printf(" "); // printing whitespace
    printf("|"); // print the right border of the cell
    len = printf("Last Name"); // len is equal to 9

    for(i=0; i<18 - len; ++i) printf(" "); // printing whitespace
    printf("|");
    len = printf("Grade 1"); // len is equal to 7

    for(i=0; i<18 - len; ++i) printf(" ");
    printf("|");
    printf("Grade 2\n");

    for(i =0 ; i<80; ++i) printf("-"); // bottom border of header
    printf("\n"); // breakline
}

void printBody(Student* students, int nbrOfStudents) {
    int j = 0; // to iterate over students
    int len = 0;
    int i =0; // for drawing
    for(j = 0; j< nbrOfStudents; ++j) {
        printf("|"); // left border of the left cell
        len = printf("%s", students[j].firstName);

        for(i=0; i<18 - len; ++i) printf(" "); // printing whitespace
        printf("|"); // print the right border of the cell
        len = printf("%s", students[j].lastName);

        for(i=0; i<18 - len; ++i) printf(" "); // printing whitespace
        printf("|");
        len = printf("%.2f", students[j].grade1);

        for(i=0; i<18 - len; ++i) printf(" "); // printing whitespace
        printf("|");
        len = printf("%.2f\n", students[j].grade2);

    }

    for(i =0 ; i<80; ++i) printf("-"); // bottom border of header
    printf("\n"); // breakline
}


int main() {
    Student students[3] = {
        createStudent("Jane", "Roberson", 99, 75),
        createStudent("Amelia", "Coeur-de-lait", 85, 89),
        createStudent("Anna", "Stone", 65, 30)
    };

    printBorder();
    printBody(students, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This might be more useful for the OP if you provided code to print a couple of example lines.

Comment: Yes, i did not quite get you

Comment: I update my awnser ! please check the example code, and if you find it useful upvote it plz :)

Comment: your answer is good, but i already solved it myself some hours ago :P, anyway tanks a lot, i might save it for a future use.